# WebBrowser Control Full Screen detection from VB6

Tags: vb6, webbrowser-control

I'm trying to detect full screen mode with WebBrowser Control...

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_OnFullScreen(ByVal FullScreen As Boolean)

 Dim itState As Integer

 itState = chkOnTop.Value

 If FullScreen = True Then
  chkOnTop.Value = vbUnchecked
 Else
  chkOnTop.Value = itState
 End If

End Sub
```

But it's not working, even if I try to get a simple return value like this (when you double click on it, to get Full Screen mode):

```
Private Sub WebBrowser1_OnFullScreen(ByVal FullScreen As Boolean)

 Form1.Caption = CStr(FullScreen)

End Sub
```

and here is the htm file called "example.htm" to load into WebBrowser Control:

```
<html>

<body topmargin="0" leftmargin="0" scroll="no">

 <iframe 
  width="640"
  height="385"
  src="http://www.youtube.com/embed/xtYIEBOQ1eQ?rel=0&autoplay=1"
  allowfullscreen="true"
  menu="false"
  frameborder="0">
</iframe>

</body>

</html>
```

Load when I press the CommandButton on the Form like this:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate App.Path & "\example.htm"
```

**So, my real question is:**

When the video is loaded into WebBrowser Control and you Double click on video then it's goes Full screen mode and if you Double click again it goes back to normal view mode.

**Now I wish to detect those events!**

Can someone help me out?

Comment: if you can please make a screendump (alt-printscreen) of your form with the webbrowser control and edit your original post to show it to us, this will probably show us more of what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768338%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) MSDN page mentions that the event isn't supported by the WebBrowser object.  However, I did find that this code:

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
WebBrowser1.FullScreen = True
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_OnFullScreen(ByVal FullScreen As Boolean)
MsgBox FullScreen
End Sub
```

successfully showed the message box with a value of True.  So, I'm not sure why this doesn't work with your second bit of code.

On the other hand, this line of code is faulty:

```
chkOnTop.Value = Unchecked
```

The correct constant is "vbUnchecked", which you won't see by looking up the CheckBox control in the VB6 doc.  (Have a look in the Constants section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa265070%28v=vs.60%29.aspx) instead; you'll see that "Unchecked" is just the description of the value 0 for the Value property, not the constant that equates to 0.)  Also, all of your lines of code with the string "itState" are redundant; you're simply storing the current value to a variable and resetting the value without ever changing it.

Comment: Hi @BobRodes, yes, you was right about "chkOnTop.Value", I edited that and please see again my question I exteded it for better understanding.

Answer (score 0):

Double clicking the form will maximize the form window, it will not make the webbrowser fullscreen.

On what do you double-click ?

make a new project of just 1 form with 1 webbrowser control and 1 timer control and put in the following code:

```
'1 form with:
'  1 webbrowser control: Name=WebBrowser1
'  1 timer control : Name=Timer1
Option Explicit

Private Sub Form_Click()
  With WebBrowser1
    .FullScreen = Not .FullScreen
  End With 'Webbrowser1
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Load()
  Timer1.Interval = 500
End Sub

Private Sub Timer1_Timer()
  Caption = CStr(Now) & " : " & CStr(WebBrowser1.FullScreen)
End Sub

Private Sub WebBrowser1_OnFullScreen(ByVal FullScreen As Boolean)
  Caption = "OnFullScreen event fired"
End Sub

Private Sub Form_Activate()
  WebBrowser1.FullScreen = True
End Sub
```

when you click on background of the form it will toggle the fullscreen-state of the webbrowser control

the timer will twice a second show the fullscreen state (prepended with the current time to show that it is the timer who shows this)

when the OnFullScreen event fires it will show so in the caption (not prepended with the current time), it will be overwritten by the timer within 500 msec, but you will see it when you pay attention

Comment: Hi @Hrqls, I did't express myself correctly, please see again my question, I extended it.

Answer (score 0):

n your Form_load add the following two lines:

```
Me.FormBorderStyle = Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.None
Me.WindowState = FormWindowState.Maximized
```

Obviously, you can place the code elsewhere than in form_load - and depending on your list of includes you may need more or less prepending.

That code became well me in my VB6 system by this form:
Me.WindowState = vbMaximized
Or:
Me.WindowState = FormWindowStateConstants.vbMaximized